# Why no manual entry for std::vector in gcc-4.9.1-4ubuntu2?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, ubuntu-14.10

I am trying to see the manual entry for c++ keywords like `std::vector,std::set,std::map, iostream,std::size()` e.t.c in terminal but it says, No manual entry for these commands. Even is show the same thing when i typed `man iostream`. `g++` is installed in my computer.

Comment: The man pages don't cover the C++ standard library, AFAIK.

Comment: I have seen, it do show result for STL as well as other C++ commands. In my case it's not even showing `man bool` `man namespace` too.

Comment: It does show for some libraries. like stdio and stuff. but not everything is covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no man support for C++ language and its feature on Linux based machine. If you really want to work with the standard documentation **online**, you may refer [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

However you may also download cppreference the complete documentation in various format and work **offline**. I recommend that you should follow this and download complete documentation archive from below location:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives

Answer (score 1):

To search for something within the man pages, use `-k` or `--apropos`, i.e. `man -k "vector"`.

To find documentation on the C++ standard library, I recommend [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), any of the books written by [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/) and the latest working draft of the [C++ standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf).

---

The man-pages scope does not encompass the C++ standard library. In particular, `man man-pages` ([online version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html)) says:

```
DESCRIPTION
        This  page describes the conventions that should be employed when writ‐
        ing man pages for the Linux  man-pages  project,  which  documents  the
        user-space API provided by the Linux kernel and the GNU C library. [..]
```

And goes on to describe the sections of the manual pages. You can also see these same sections in `man man`. For example, it might look like:

```
   Sections of the manual pages
       The manual Sections are traditionally defined as follows:

       1 Commands (Programs)
                 Those commands that can be executed by the user from within
                 a shell.

       2 System calls
                 Those functions which must be performed by the kernel.

       3 Library calls
                 Most of the libc functions.

       4 Special files (devices)
                 Files found in /dev.

       5 File formats and conventions
                 The format for /etc/passwd and other human-readable files.

       6 Games

       7 Overview, conventions, and miscellaneous
                 Overviews of various topics, conventions and protocols,
                 character set standards, and miscellaneous other things.

       8 System management commands
                 Commands like mount(8), many of which only root can
                 execute.
```